# How to match this regex to extract the following pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a large string that has an id and two words in spanish:

```
large__string = '''
Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083
mañanita mañana RG 0.796611
, , Fc 1
buscando buscar VMG0000 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
sorprender sorprender VMN0000 1
a a SPS00 0.996023
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
persona persona NCFS000 0.98773
muy muy RG 1
especial especial AQ0CS0 1
para para SPS00 0.999103
nosotros nosotros PP1MP000 1
, , Fc 1
y y CC 0.999962
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
. . Fp 1

Pero pero CC 0.999764
vamos ir VMIP1P0 0.655914
a a SPS00 0.996023
lo el DA0NS0 0.457533
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ninguna ninguno DI0S3DF 0.345344
error error A3FSD23 1
interesa interesar VMIP3S0 0.994868
LO_QUE_INTERESA_La lo_que_interesa_la NP00000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
clasificación clasificación NCFS000 1
A+ a+ NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ahorran ahorrar VMIP3P0 1
energía energía NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
si si CS 0.99954
no no RN 0.998134
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
equivoco equivocar VMIP1S0 1
. . Fp 1

Lava lavar VMIP3S0 0.397388
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
7 7 Z 1
kg kilogramo NCMN000 1
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.998134
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
nada nada RG 0.135196
mal mal RG 0.497537
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
le le PP3CSD00 1
veía ver VMII3S0 0.62272
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gran gran AQ0CS0 1
tambor tambor NCMS000 1
( ( Fpa 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
acero acero NCMS000 0.973481
inoxidable inoxidable AQ0CS0 1
) ) Fpt 1
y y CC 0.999962
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
consumo consumo NCMS000 0.948927
máximo máximo AQ0MS0 0.986111
de de SPS00 0.999984
49 49 Z 1
litros litro NCMP000 1
Mandos mandos NP00000 1
intuitivos intuitivo AQ0MP0 1
, , Fc 1
todo todo PI0MS000 0.43165
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
explicado explicar VMP00SM 1
, , Fc 1
nada nada PI0CS000 0.850279
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ver ver VMN0000 0.997382
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
de de SPS00 0.999984
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
de de SPS00 0.999984
mis mi DP1CPS 0.995868
padres padre NCMP000 1
Además además NP00000 1
incluye incluir VMIP3S0 0.994868
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
tecnología tecnología NCFS000 1
Textileprotec textileprotec NP00000 1
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
protege proteger VMIP3S0 0.994868
nuestras nuestro DP1FPP 0.994186
ninguna ninguno DI0S3DF 0.345344
falla falla NCFSD23 1
prendas prenda NCFP000 0.95625
más más RG 1
preciadas preciar VMP00PF 1
. . Fp 1'''
```

I would like to extract in a list `ninguno` followed by the `id` (to the right) and the second word that have as `id` `NC_ _ _ _ _`. Where `_ _ _ _ _` are free characters of the `id`, they must be consecutive (i.e. they must have this precedence ninguno followed by NC, they must be "together"). For example let's focus in this pattern:

```
ninguna ninguno DI0S3DF 0.345344
falla falla NCFSD23 1
```

for large__string I would like to extract this as:

```
[('ninguno', 'DI0S3DF'), ('falla', 'NCFSD23')]
```

This is what I tried:

```
pattern__ = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(ninguno)\s[0-9.]+\n^(.+)\s.+\s(NC)', large__string)
```

But I get an empty list. The regex is wrong, how can I create a regex that extract the above pattern?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but for starters in your regex you have `(ninguno)\s[0-9.]+\n`, which means "ninguno" must be followed by as space and then a digit or period, which is clearly not the text you want to match.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Yes... maybe Im confused with this task. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.findall` method.

```
>>> s = '''Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083
mañanita mañana RG 0.796611
, , Fc 1
buscando buscar VMG0000 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
sorprender sorprender VMN0000 1
a a SPS00 0.996023
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
persona persona NCFS000 0.98773
muy muy RG 1
especial especial AQ0CS0 1
para para SPS00 0.999103
nosotros nosotros PP1MP000 1
, , Fc 1
y y CC 0.999962
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
. . Fp 1

Pero pero CC 0.999764
vamos ir VMIP1P0 0.655914
a a SPS00 0.996023
lo el DA0NS0 0.457533
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
interesa interesar VMIP3S0 0.994868
LO_QUE_INTERESA_La lo_que_interesa_la NP00000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
clasificación clasificación NCFS000 1
A+ a+ NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ahorran ahorrar VMIP3P0 1
energía energía NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
si si CS 0.99954
no no RN 0.998134
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
equivoco equivocar VMIP1S0 1
. . Fp 1

Lava lavar VMIP3S0 0.397388
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
7 7 Z 1
kg kilogramo NCMN000 1
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.998134
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
nada nada RG 0.135196
mal mal RG 0.497537
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
le le PP3CSD00 1
veía ver VMII3S0 0.62272
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gran gran AQ0CS0 1
tambor tambor NCMS000 1
( ( Fpa 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
acero acero NCMS000 0.973481
inoxidable inoxidable AQ0CS0 1
) ) Fpt 1
y y CC 0.999962
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
consumo consumo NCMS000 0.948927
máximo máximo AQ0MS0 0.986111
de de SPS00 0.999984
49 49 Z 1
litros litro NCMP000 1
Mandos mandos NP00000 1
intuitivos intuitivo AQ0MP0 1
, , Fc 1
todo todo PI0MS000 0.43165
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
explicado explicar VMP00SM 1
, , Fc 1
nada nada PI0CS000 0.850279
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ver ver VMN0000 0.997382
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
de de SPS00 0.999984
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
de de SPS00 0.999984
mis mi DP1CPS 0.995868
padres padre NCMP000 1
Además además NP00000 1
incluye incluir VMIP3S0 0.994868
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
tecnología tecnología NCFS000 1
Textileprotec textileprotec NP00000 1
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
protege proteger VMIP3S0 0.994868
nuestras nuestro DP1FPP 0.994186
ninguna ninguno DI0S3DF 0.345344
falla falla NCFSD23 1
prendas prenda NCFP000 0.95625
más más RG 1
preciadas preciar VMP00PF 1
. . Fp 1'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^.*?\b(ninguno)\s+(\S+)\s+[0-9.]+\n.*?\s(\S+)\s+(NC\S+)\s+[0-9.]+$', s)
[('ninguno', 'DI0S3DF', 'falla', 'NCFSD23')]
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP0xU1/5)

Since there are 4 capturing groups used, you must get a list of tuples of 4 items each.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I am getting confused with this. :)

Comment: I edited the question. I guess that this regex catches when `nunca id` and the word consecutevely to it. This regex must catch `nunca id` and the word cosecutevely if and only if it has as id `NC _ _ _ _ _` where the blank spaces are free characters of the id. Any idea of how to fix this?... the precedence was ok. This is the desired output:`[(ninguno, DI0S3DF), (falla, NCFSD23) ]`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I really apreciate it but I got this empty list: `[]
`

Comment: I do the following: `pattern__ = re.findall(r'^.*?\b(ninguno)\s+(\S+)\s+[0-9.]+\n.*?\s(\S+)\s+(NC\S+)\s+[0-9.]+$', s)


print pattern__` and this is the output `[]`, thanks!

Comment: oh sorry , forget the multiline modifier `(?m)`. Now it should work.